# How to detect why a process terminated programatically in Linux

Tags: linux, process

Processes are terminated for one of three reasons: they've reached end of execution (nominal case), they contain an uncaught exception (synchronous crash), or they've received some signal that they are not handling (asynchronous crash). Within the design of a program, we can instrument ways of at least detecting each of these (e.g., catch statements, signal handlers, etc.).

Suppose I wanted to design a program that can monitor another program's execution in Linux. I can easily tell if the program terminated by noticing its PID disappearing from `/proc`, but I won't know why. Is there a way to observe the target program to determine the cause of termination?

Comment: The best way to get the info is to be the process' parent and `wait` for it.  So either you can query the parent process (eg, the parent can provide an interface or log the data), or you can become the parent (via ptrace).

Answer (score 2):

The main limitation is the amount of details you need. At the operating system level, you can basically only count for exit code or signal that killed the process.

Depending on your restrictions, there are multiple options:

1. `wait` - allows for quick notification (blocking call or signal), but only works for immediate children.
2. `ptrace`, directly (rather tricky) or via the `strace` command; it has limitations, e.g. a single process can only be ptraced by one process at a time, but it allows to specify a list of syscalls to monitor, so it does not need to be as slow as default invocation of strace.
3. BSD Process Accounting. Typically requires root privileges to access, and definitely requires them to turn it on (it's global). Once it's running, you can effectively watch a file which grows an entry for every finishing process, including exit code / signal, either programmatically (the `ac_exitcode` field in the acct struct) or via the `lastcomm` command (c.f. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lastcomm.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Processes are terminated for one of three reasons: **(a)** they've reached end of execution (nominal case), **(b)** they contain an uncaught exception (synchronous crash), or **(c)** they've received some signal that they are not handling (asynchronous crash).

I'm not sure what **(a)** should mean -- even if a program returns from its `main()` function, it's still terminating by explicitly calling the `_exit(2)` (or `exit_group(2)`) system call (from the C runtime code that called `main()` in the first place). If it doesn't call `_exit()`, it will *crash*.

Also, I don't see what difference is between **(b)** and **(c)**: they would receive a signal in both cases -- which they could either catch, block or ignore (except for `SIGKILL` -- or `SIGSTOP`, but the latter won't terminate the process).

> Suppose I wanted to design a program that can monitor another program's execution in Linux.

Then, you should imitate what `strace(1)` or `gdb(1)` are doing: use `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH)`, etc. For instance, this will only monitor the exit of a process, not all its system calls:

```
strace -e trace=none -p PID   
strace -e trace=exit,exit_group -p PID
```

The `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT` option of `ptrace(2)` is interesting:

> `The tracee is stopped early  during  process  exit,  when registers are still available, allowing the tracer to see where the exit occurred, whereas the normal exit  notification  is  done  after  the process is finished exiting.`

Linux also has the [proc connector](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9f46080c41d5f3f7c00b4e169ba4b0b2865258bf) netlink interface, which allows you to monitor processes without stopping or affecting them in any way. It only works as root, though. A sample program using the proc connector interface is `forkstat(1)`:

```
forkstat -e exit   # will show all exiting processes
stdbuf -oL forkstat -e exit | grep -m1 PID  # will only show when PID exits
```